# Some questions of using  HSQL to presentation data in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, hsqldb

friends, I am using with jasper to present a sample report names `AddressesReport`, by the tutorial I can see various format report after running ant, but I want to know how the data in "AddressesReport" is fetched from HSQLDB to the report template. Detailed things like

1. Is there any **Store Procedure** for batch-fetching from HSQLDB table `address` ？
2. then, how these fetched field stored in jasper template named `*.jrxml`？

HSQLDB has Sqltool due to the [document](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/util-guide.pdf), but how can I running scripting like "select * from address" in HSQLDBMS? Can somebody give a help? thanks first.

Comment: After error and trials ,I am sure Jasper absolutely can call store procedure in *.jrxml's <querystring> section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows how to connect to an existing HSQLDB database to create reports:

http://www.uptick.com.au/content/working-hsqldb-jasperreports-and-ireport